# How should I join Option[Future[T]]?

Tags: scala

I have the following code

```
import scala.concurrent.{Future, Await}
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration

import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def later(v: Int) = Future.successful(v)

val data = List(
  (1, Some(1), Some(2)),
  (2, Some(1), None),
  (3, None, Some(2)),
  (4, None, None)
)

def wait[T](v: Future[T]) = Await.result(v, Duration.Inf)


def seq[T](v: Option[Future[T]]): Future[Option[T]] = Future.sequence(v.toList).map(_.headOption)
def join[A, B](a: Option[Future[A]], b: Option[Future[B]]): Future[(Option[A], Option[B])] = seq(a).zip(seq(b))

wait(Future.sequence(data.map{ case (a, b, c) =>
  join(b.map(later), c.map(later)).map((a, _))
})) == List(
  (1, ((Some(1), Some(2)))),
  (2, ((Some(1), None))),
  (3, ((None, Some(2)))),
  (4, ((None, None)))
)
```

I was wondering if there is any other way to write the `join` function

Comment: Of course there are other ways. Is there a better way? I don't think so, certainly not any of the answers posted up until now (no offense). What exactly are you looking for in an alternative implementation?

Comment: @jedesah I'm under the impression that there is another way to sequence those futures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are open to using Scalaz, you can omit the conversions between `Option` and `List` to be able to `sequence` the two values.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import scalaz.syntax.traverse._

def join[A, B](o1: Option[Future[A]], o2: Option[Future[B]]) =
  o1.sequence zip o2.sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using other helper functions:

```
  def join[A, B](a: Option[Future[A]], b: Option[Future[B]]): Future[(Option[A], Option[B])] =
    (a, b) match {
      case (Some(fa), Some(fb)) =>
        for {
          vfa <- fa
          vfb <- fb
        } yield Some(vfa) -> Some(vfb)
      case (Some(fa), None) => fa map (Some(_) -> None)
      case (None, Some(fb)) => fb map (None -> Some(_))
      case _ => Future.successful(None -> None)
    }
```